# Insert multiple records with values based on each other

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Sorry for the bad title, I havent come up with a better one yet.

I am currently optimising a tool which basically does thousands of selects and inserts.

Assume the following relation

```
class A
{
    public long ID; // This is an automatic key by the sqlserver
    ...Some other values
}

class B
{ 
    public long RefID // Reference to A.ID;
    ... some other values...
}

class C
{ 
    public long RefID // Reference to A.ID;
    ... some other values
}
```

What currently is happening is a SELECT to get ObjectA,
if it doesnt exist, create a new one. The Query returns the ID (OUTPUT INSERTED.ID)

Then it selects (inserts if not existant) the objects B and C.

Is there a way to compress this into a single SQL statement?

Im struggling at the part where the automatic generation of object A happens.

So it must do something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE someConditions)
    INSERT... and get the ID
ELSE
    REMEMBER THE ID?

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableB WERE RefID = ourRememberedID)
    INSERT...

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableC WERE RefID = ourRememberedID)
    INSERT...
```

Please note, stored procedures cannot be used.

Comment: You can use a procedure that does all that, then you call the procedure passing whatever values you want and do the logic there in one call.

Comment: Sadly, stored procedures are no option in this environment...

Comment: Stored procedures aren't an option? In 2014?

Comment: You know its not only about science progression sometimes...

Comment: Then what is it about?

Comment: About not beeing the owner of the db and not having the rights to create stored procedures...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little help
You could issue these three in one statement 
Use a DataReader NextResult

```
select ID from FROM TableA WHERE someConditions
select count(*) from TableB where refID = (select ID from FROM TableA WHERE someConditions)
select count(*) from TableC where refID = (select ID from FROM TableA WHERE someConditions)
```

But even then you take a risk the TableB or TableC had an insert before you got to it

If I could not use a stored procedure I think I would load the data into a #temp using a TVP
I think you could craft 4 statements in a transaction

Comment: Im doing it that way now, saves 2/3 of the time